# Querying Jobs for a Customer

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to query Jobs for a specific Customer, but am running into a little issue.  It appears that the ParentRef is not queryable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-02-19T10:20:31.635-08:00">
  <Fault type="ValidationFault">
    <Error code="4001">
      <Message>Invalid query</Message>
      <Detail>QueryValidationError: property 'ParentRef' is not queryable</Detail>
    </Error>
  </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

However, that's the only thing I can think of to limit the query on the server-side.  In the old world, we submitted a Filter of `CustomerId :EQUALS: #{id}` to the Jobs API, but now the Customer/Job APIs have been combined.  My v3 query is `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Job = true AND ParentRef = '#{id}'` which seems like a reasonable thing to do.

Am I missing something?  Could you allow us to query on ParentRef?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this works OK:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE FullyQualifiedName LIKE 'Your Customer Name:%'
```

Comment: Indeed - that's a good solution, thanks Keith!  I was hoping to solve it without a LIKE, but this gets us there.

Answer (score 0):

the above works if you only have one level.  Try a cast:

```
if (null != cust.ParentRef && ((ReferenceType)cust.ParentRef).Value == c.Id)
```

Then if you were building a treeview for instance just wrap it in a recursive method.